# How to transfer USDT BEP-20 token to another account, smart contract deployed on binance smart chain

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, web3modal

I am developing a DAPP(Decentralized Application) using html, vanilla javascript(module system) for the frontend with
these packages-

**PACKAGES**

```
@wagmi/core
@walletconnect/ethereum-provider
@walletconnect/modal
@web3modal/html
ethers
viem
```

**PACKAGE BUNDLER**

```
webpack
babel
```

I want the user to transfer USDT BEP-20 tokens to another account
the Smart Contract is on Mainnet binance smart chain(BSC)

this is the code, that is being used to transfer tokens from front end

```
const transaction = wagmi.prepareSendTransaction({
    to: transferToAccount,
    value: viem.parseEther(transferAmount, "wei")
});
```

`const {hash} = wagmi.sendTransaction(transaction);`

this is the code to add into the block chain

```
const { request } = wagmi.prepareWriteContract({
    address: contractAddress,
    abi: abi,
    functionName: "addToBlockchain",
    args: [
    transferToAccount,
    viem.parseEther(transferAmount, "wei"),
    transferMessage,
    transferKeyword,
    ],
    });
const { hash }=wagmi.writeContract(request);
```

> **when user transfers some amount into another account it only transfers BNB token not USDT(BEP-20)**
> I need help on how to achieve USDT(BEP-20) transfer to another account not BNB token`